How many kms do aluminum rims last when ridden in city and/or road conditions?
How many kms do alu rims last when ridden in city and/or road conditions?
I understand that durability is critically dependent on several factors like riding conditions, spoke count, quality of rim/wheel, rider weight etc. Please no general answers explaining this. I only want real experiences of wearing out alu rims from every day use. You are welcome to add the mentioned data to your answer to provide some background/speculate on the cause of a very early failure etc.
Failure from accute accidents/crashes do not count, but unexpected failure from normal use does count (e.g if your rim exploded/cracked after a 10-15cm drop you had done 100 times before it counts, riding your rim into a brick wall does not). I'm interested in how man km you got just riding normally (or years of riding with a km guesstimate), with the unfortunate pot-hole now and then, curb edge here and there before the rim developed cracks etc that made you decide to replace it.
If you claim they last indefinately, please post how many km you have reached.

Rims for rim brakes or disc brakes?

Both are relevant. I'm mostly interested in failure at spoke interface, but others might be interested in other causes so either is fine.

No wheel I've bought new has failed under my ownership.  At least 4 rims have failed but none of them were bought new; they were all unknown mileage at acquisition.   So, a null return is my best contribution.

Your current "max mileage with no issues" on a set of rims would be valuable additional information.

This isn't a question, it's a survey.

@DanGao This is a question. I just didn't want unsubstansiated bs answers or meaningless comments like yours.

Got an alu wheelset based on cheap Alexrims. Had a fairly hard life. Frequently ridden loaded. Occasional offroad use. Multiple crashes (no front collisions though). Pulling child trailer too.  ~ 35 000km and not showing any warning signs.
During the lifetime of the wheelset, had front re-laced once (to replace worn out hub) and rear relaced twice (hub replacemet and broken spokes while riding loaded bike offroad)
Would bet this wheelset will still be here for next decade.

Out of curiosity, what size (559 or 622) and spoke count do these excellent rims have?


32 spokes front and rear. Laced in 3x cross pattern. Eyeletted spoke holes. Won't be able to tell the exact model as I got the bike second hand.



If you claim they last indefinately, please post how many km you have reached.

There are two aspects here. First is how long a wheel lasts. The failure mode of a poorly built wheel is a total and complete loss of spoke tension on all spokes. If the rim is double wall and not the lightestweight rim you can find, this total and complete loss of spoke tension doesn't cause the rim to fail, you can rebuilt the wheel to a higher and more equal spoke tension and it will work. My experience is that this total and complete loss of spoke tension on all spokes happens usually in 1000 km, if it's ever going to happen.
On a well built wheel, there are three concerns:

If you have rim brakes, they slowly eat the sidewalls. I have never worn a sidewall to rim brake track wear so I can't say how long it is until it happens, but probably far more than disc brake rotors wear in (about 10 000 km).

Road damage can damage the rim. But, these are infrequent events and depend so much on the riding style, that it may take some unlucky and careless persons 5000 km to get a damaged rim, and somebody else may get 100 000 km of use from a rim. Some damage may be repairable.

If the rim is anodized and/or does not have double eyelets, the rim may begin to crack at the spoke holes. Once this happens, it's game over, the damage will only get worse and the rim must be replaced. This can be avoided by never choosing rims that are anodized (not all black rims are anodized, most are powder coated probably for the reason that anodizing reduces the fatigue life of rims), and never choosing rims that do not have double eyelets.


Sorry to not have accurate statistical data since I haven't ridden enough to have damaged rims, but at least this answer provides some useful information on how rims fail. And the answer may be "indefinitely" if you have disc brakes, choose sturdy rims, ride carefully, choose powder coated rims, and choose rims with double eyelets.
